# Changing the unique page address

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a Page where i display ads from the database and for each ad I have a separate page that is generated dynamically. Here code:

```
$id_ad = $_GET['id'];
    $pull_info=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id_random=$id_ad"); 
    foreach ($pull_info as $pull_info_res) {      
        $id             = $pull_info_res->id;
        $active         = $pull_info_res->active;
        $title          = $pull_info_res->title;
        $content          = $pull_info_res->content;
        }
```

The address of each advertisement is: http://mypage.pl/advertisement/?id=1114242
My question is this. How can you get rid of this "?id=" so that it only left this:1114242 (http://mypage.pl/advertisement/1114242).

**EDIT:**
I used add_rewrite_rule insted of htaccess and it's finally working :)
 In functions.php (wordpress):

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'advertisement/([^/]+)/?',
         'index.php?pagename=advertisement&designer_slug=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'designer_slug';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

And in ads.php

```
$id_ad = $wp_query->query_vars['designer_slug'];
    $pull_info=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id_random=$id_ad");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `.htaccess` rewrites. Check this [tutorial](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) for more information.

You'd want something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^advertisement/([0-9]+)$ advertisement/?id=$1 [NC,L]
```